# Manage component life in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm working on the vuejs, I have the following problems:
- I have a method that receives a list of records through an api rest, it is executed from time to time automatically, the method also has a validation in case the sent token is active, otherwise it redirects to the system login; The detail here is that the method is still running. The way I do the redirection is as follows.

```
if(error.response.status == 401){
              that.$swal('Su token ha expirado', 'Vuelva a ingresar sus credenciales de acceso.', "info")
              that.$store.dispatch("logout").then(() => {
                that.$router.push("/login");
              });
            }
```

- The list of records has for each item a More Information button, where a Modal component is opened in which videos and audios are displayed, when playing any of them and then closing the modal one continues listening to the audio, so the component follows active.

In both situations it seems that the component is not destroyed or is not deactivated, because it is still running in the background. Please I need guidance regarding this, thanks for your answers and contributions.

Comment: Your `dispatch("logout").then(...)` seems to be the issue to me. Can you also post the content of your store action ?

Comment: Okay so your store action looks okay, it might come from your video or audio stream. I guess you have to look into the documentation of your video/audio library and find the method that would allow you to stop the stream. It's often a `disconnect()`, `stop()`, `destroy()` or `remove()` method. Once you find it, you can call it on modal close.